# How can I call a function when clicked on a button?

Tags: javascript, angular, function, button

Basically I have just started MEAN stack

I want to call a function on a button click
this is what I am trying to do :

this is my html file

```
<button (click = func())>Click here!</button>
```

this is my `.ts` file

```
func(){
console.log("called a function on a button click")
}
```

your help will mean me a lot!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @JorgeB Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '(click' is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue in your html while binding `click` event.

Try below code:

```
<button (click)="func()">Click here!</button>
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be "() => func()" ?

Comment: No. This is not an arrow function. This is a function defined in ts file and we directly bind it with (click) even as per Angular syntax.

Comment: In angular2+ it's simply "func()". I haven't used AngularJS in quite some time, but back when I was using it I think it was ng-click="expression".

Comment: Yes in Angular 1.x, it was ng-click but there as well we pass function like this only.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button (click)="func()">Click here!</button>


func(){
console.log("called a function on a button click")
}
```

this  should work for you

Comment: Shouldnt it be "() => func()" ?

Comment: no this should work

Answer (score 1):

you html should be like this :

```
<button (click)="func()">Click here!</button>
```

and in you .ts class :

```
func(){
console.log("called a function on a button click")
}
```